# Date: option requires an argument

Tags: bash, shell, date

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

I've got this block of code

```
  if [ -n "${MFA_Exp}" ]; then
    exp_sec="$(expr '(' $(date -d "${MFA_Exp}" +%s) - $(date +%s) ')' )";
    if [ "${exp_sec}" -gt 0 ]; then
      output+=", MFA TTL: $(date -u -d @"${exp_sec}" +"%Hh %Mm %Ss")";
    else
      output+=", MFA DEAD!";
    fi;
```

that should output the expiration time of my MFA token, but I get this error

```
date: option requires an argument -- d
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

I'm on a Macbook and I suspect it's something to do with the date format.
I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: You are likely on MacOS using FreeBSD `date` syntax. The one you posted with `-d` is GNU specific

Comment: By the way, you don't need `expr`: `exp_sec=$(( $(date ...) - $(date +%s) ))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default date format for BSD `date` is `[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]]`. If `MFS_Exp` is in that format, you can use

```
exp_sec=$(( $(date -j "$MFS_Exp" +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
```

If not, you need to specify the input format using the `-f` option. For example, if your string is like `2020-12-18 12:34:56`, then use `date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$MFS_Exp" +%s`.

For the second call, I wouldn't recommend using `date` at all, as you are working with a duration, not a timestamp.

```
hours=$(( exp_sec / 3600 ))
rem=$(( exp_sec % 3600 ))
minutes=$(( rem / 60 ))
sec=$(( rem % 60 ))
output+=", MFA TTL: ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${sec}s"
```

Comment: This is what the output of my string looks like `2020-12-20T23:28:16+00:00`. I just need to figure out the input format for this would be.

Comment: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%S+00:00`.

Comment: It's throwing up this error `Failed conversion of ``2020-12-21T02:00:12+00:00'' using format ``%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%S+00:00''`

I feel like I'm doing something wrong now, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I missed the colon between `%M` and `%S`.